# Using OpenCV how could I crop an image based on the x and y coordinates, and allow that x and y coordinate to be the center of the crop?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I have attempted to crop images using OpenCV. I already have the coordinates for the specific parts of the images that I want cropped. The problem that I am having is that since when you use a rectangle to crop in opencv the coordinates you give it are the top left of the rectangle, so in my case its cutting off half of a face since I have the coordinates centered in the middle of the face. Is there anyway to make it so that the x and y cords given start in the center of the rectangle so that you can create a portion to crop, from the inside out, not from the outside in? I am also fine with listening to other suggestions for how I could achieve this task.

Comment: Whatever your center coordinates, subtract 50 on x and 50 on y for example before you feed it to the crop images function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that openCV has a way to force the crop to be based off of the center of the image, but the solution is pretty simple anyways.

Right now you have something like `cv::Rect imageToCrop(X, Y, Width, Height);`

Change it to: `cv::Rect imageToCrop(X - (Width/2), Y - (Height/2), Width, Height);`

And that will center it around your X and Y